# Changing opacity on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The ultimate goal of my project is to make my image of circle chart interactive on mouseovers. I want the pieces of the circle to change opacity to .5 (from 1) when the user hovers them. I have an image of the chart but I'm not sure how to make areas of one single image change opacity on hover. I have tried several things:

- I image mapped the chart with each piece in its own map, but I wasn't sure how to change opacity of an area of one single image (css)(if its even possible)
- My second approach was that i sliced the chart up into individual pieces and made their opacity .5 and saved them all separately. Then, I image mapped the single image of the chart and tried to load the individual piece on hover (css)
- My final approach was saving each piece of the chart as individual images and when the image is hovered, change the opacity to .5 with css. This works perfectly except i am not sure how to position the pieces to form a perfect circle in dreamweaver.

Any direction or advise is greatly appreciated. I am willing to learn javascript or jquery to help get this done.

Thank you

**EDIT** Image of the chart is now attached

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwIfY.jpg

Comment: Can you maybe put an example of what you're trying to achieve on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I have attached the image of the chart

Comment: If I save each color piece as its own image, how can I position them in that manner?

Comment: Maybe you should use html mapping see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: I can successfully create the image map, but is it possible to change the opacity of image map areas?

Comment: no unless you dinamically draw the image in an html5 canvas. Only other options is overlapping many pngs with transparent background. See my answer

Comment: Eventually this may be of your interest: http://alistapart.com/article/sprites demo: http://d.alistapart.com/sprites/ala-image3.html

Comment: Why not make all of the images have the same canvas size as the entire chart and then just place all of the images on top of eachother. (if that makes sense)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nevermind, my idea was similar to a response below which you said you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question right regarding the current answers but if you want to make the parts of the chart interactive I have 2 approaches:

1. To achieve the effect with pure CSS I guess you need to divide the chart in individual images as you already mentioned. The positioning is quite simple. I've used in my demo below one image an let it rotate. In your case you can cut each part of the chart individually and get the right place for them with absolute positionig.
2. Again as you already mentioned you can use map area to define the parts of the chart. With a plugin like this: [ImageMapster](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster) you can achieve what you want. I've used this once for the following [map](http://blackbeats.fm/events/). It's again very simple, when hovering any part of the map it's background will be replaced by another background. In your case you could save the chart with full opacity and display on hover an image of the chart with 50% opacity.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4t2GU/)

The Demo is not very clean as I didn't spent much time in position the parts perfectly but you can see how it works.

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if CSS3 transition will fit to you:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
.chart-item { opacity: 0.5; transition:opacity 2s; }
.chart-item:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

Check documentation for browser support.

Comment: Would this be able to work on different areas of a single image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a div and put each image as the background or content of one div (in order), then create a listener for the div class to change opacity upon `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` using jQuery.

Here's a simple example (pardon any mistakes):

jQuery:

```
$( ".somedivclass" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.5);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
  });
```

[Here's](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) more info on `$.mouseenter()`.  [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) some for `$.fadeTo()`.

Comment: If I save each piece as its own image, how can I position them like the image I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo. Hover your cursor exactly on the eyes of the owl, and you will see the opacity changing. It will not change if you hover on the rest of the image.

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/14/**

```
$('.eye1').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeToggle(1500)
});
```

Comment: This is great and the right idea, but how would I go applying this to different ares of a single image?

Comment: Is there supposed to be any content in the Result box?

Comment: @user3087325 what do you mean?

Comment: @user3087325 hover exactly on the eye of the owl. the opacity will start changing. Elsewhere on the picture, it will not.

Comment: I'll try loading a different image in there, my work blocked the ur

Comment: The div surrounding the eye is a box so that would not work in my case because of the shape and closeness of the pieces

Comment: @user3087325 ask your question in d3.js or raphael.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using svg. Here is an implementation of exactly what you are trying to do, because I felt like learning [d3.js](http://d3js.org) today:

http://jsfiddle.net/6m26k/1/

You don't need to make the chart through code though, because you can just load the svg onto the page with html5 and use css similar to mine:

```
.arc.filled:hover {
   opacity: .8;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```